# Split string with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

when people load a image url directly I would like to send them to the page. My image urls are exactly like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/images/photos/part1_part2.JPG
```

I need to split it on the underscore and get rid of `part2.JPG` and keep `part1` and put that on the end of this url:

```
http://www.mysite.com/cgi-bin/photo.cgi?part1
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you expect the browser to _redirect_ to the .cgi URL and change the user's address bar, or just to internally rewrite the request silently to the .cgi URL?

Comment: @user3314910: What do you actually mean by `when people load a image url directly`? Do you want to prevent hot-linking?